# create generic LostFocus event handler in c#

Tags: c#, event-handling

Here is the situation:

http://i962.photobucket.com/albums/ae103/kashyaprakesh/misc/denominationwindow.jpg

I have text boxes to left which accepts denomination values and other text box to right gives the total value for eg. in 1000's label's left textbox if I put value as 5 then to right the value is 5000.

I used lostFocus event handler to do this, but is it necessary to do the lost focus event handler for each and every textbox? There will surely be an other way.

```
 private void textBox6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        if (textBox6.Text == "")
        {
            string y = "0";
            textBox6.Text = y;
            textBox8.Text = y;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox8.Text = populateTotalAmount(textBox6.Text, 1000);

        }
        textBox8.ReadOnly = true;
    }

    private string populateTotalAmount(string denominations, int value)
    {
        int totalVal = Int32.Parse(denominations) * value;
        return totalVal.ToString();
    }
```

I would like to create a generic event handler which works on `LostFocus` event and also I need to pass different value(ie, 500,100, etc etc etc)
so that I can use that value to send it `populateTotalAmount` function.

Comment: Completely off topic note: you shouldn't use the letter x to mark multiplications, use × instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's no compelling reason to not just simply iterate the text boxes and calculate the result.  This code runs at human time, she can't tell the difference between a microsecond and millisecond.

Now you can have *one* Leave event handler for *all* text boxes.  TextChanged would work too, but is a wee disorienting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WinForms, you can create a custom control has the multiplication value as a property and then add that control to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (haven't tested it)

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
   if (ctrl is TextBox && ctrl.Name.StartsWith("math"))
      ctrl.Focused += OnFocus;
}
```